# Is it possible to edit the axes labels for a mosaic plot from the vcd package?

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

```
data("HairEyeColor")
mosaic(HairEyeColor, shade = TRUE)
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Are there arguments I can use to change the labels on the margins of the resulting plot above? For instance, I'd like to change "Male" to "M", "Female" to "F", to avoid text encroachment, and make some notes in the title labels.

I can't find anything about editing axis labels in the package's help page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lnames <- list(Sex = c("M", "F"))
mosaic(HairEyeColor, set_labels=lnames, shade=T)
```

Or...

```
mosaic(HairEyeColor, set_labels=list(Sex = c("M", "F")), shade=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The **vcd** package has an intricate system for adjusting labels -- see [Labeling in the Strucplot Framework](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/trunk/vcd/inst/doc/labeling.pdf?revision=506&root=vcd&pathrev=506).

Labels can be abbreviated with `abbreviate_labs`. The vector order matches the order of the splits: `Hair`, `Eye`, `Sex`.

```
vcd::mosaic(HairEyeColor, shade = TRUE, labeling_args = list(abbreviate_labs = c(5, 5, 1)))
```

[image: mosaic plot]

Answer (score 2):

I'd add that you can augment the space between labels in case there are too many labels, changing this parameter:

```
spacing = vcd::spacing_conditional(sp = unit(0.3, "lines"), start = unit(2, "lines"), rate = 1.8)
```

Specifically, you must change `sp = unit(0.3, "lines")` instead of 0.3 which is the default value.